# How to find details of disk usage in DB2 on Cloud

Tags: db2

We have provisioned a flex DB2 on CLoud PaaS service with 250GB disk space. 
How do we know how much of that is used for tablespaces, activelogs, tempspace, installation directory and so on?

Since this is a managed service and has no host login, if anyone knows how to get the split of disk space usage is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of monitoring table functions available in Db2 to get such an information.

Tablespaces:
[MON_GET_TABLESPACE table function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053943.html)

```
select 
  sum(case when tbsp_content_type not like '%TEMP' then tbsp_total_pages end * tbsp_page_size)/power(2, 20) data_mb
, sum(case when tbsp_content_type     like '%TEMP' then tbsp_total_pages end * tbsp_page_size)/power(2, 20) temp_mb  
from table(mon_get_tablespace(null, -2));
```

Transaction logs:
[MON_GET_TRANSACTION_LOG table function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0059253.html)

```
select (total_log_used+total_log_available)/power(2, 20) total_log_mb
from table(mon_get_transaction_log(-2));
```

[Environment routines and views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.rtn.doc/doc/c0061227.html).

You may want to check other functions near these links as well.